# Save text with links in a SQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, postgresql

I'd like to create `Post` functionality similar to Facebook. I'd like users to be able to mention others and for the mention to hyperlink to a users page.

What is the best way to save this text? The approach that I'm thinking is to save the text along with the hyperlink in a text field in PostgreSQL.

```
"Thanks <a href="/johnny">Johnny</a>"
```

However, this approach lacks structure. For example, there is no database entry relating johnny to mentions.

What's the best way to save this data?

Comment: Why not store full path for user in `href` e.g. `<a href="/users/10001">Johnny</a>`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh that's what I was referring to above. The issue is that you then don't have a reference to that mention if you want to build it more fully featured with a notifications center

Comment: "Best way"? What are you optimizing for?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev simplicity

Comment: @user2954587: then what you have in the question is the second simplest thing you can possibly do. The first would be some kind of shortcode. `"Thanks [@johnny]"` or something like that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how would you track mentions? Create a one to many with a comment and mention? Are there advtanges to saving it as [@Johnny] vs with an a tag? thanks

Comment: @user2954587: "Are there advtanges to saving it as [@Johnny] vs with an a tag" - simplicity. Tracking mentions (whatever it is you mean by this) is out of scope of saving comment to the database. That's a whole new business feature, which has to be defined/spec'ed before you start designing database for it.

Comment: @user2954587: minimal useful implementation for mentioning/pinging could look like this: upon saving a comment, you detect the mentioned users in it, and create a notification object of some kind, which links to this comment. Still absolutely orthogonal to how you store actual text of the comment (which is the question here)